# Number of zero-solutions for two bivariate polynomials $p$ and $q$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

If I consider two bivariate polynomials $p,q \in \mathbb{C}\left[ x,y \right]$ where $p$ has total degree $m$ and $q$ has total degree $n$. To keep things simple I'm not interested in special cases where $p$ and $q$ share full-dimensional components, so let's assume that $p$ and $q$ have no common polynomial factors.
$$
\begin{cases}
p(x,y) = 0 & \deg p = m\\
q(x,y) = 0 & \deg q = n
\end{cases}
$$

It's clear that the number of solutions is finite, because (by assumption) $p$ and $q$ do not share a full-dimensional component.

Is there a way to find the number of solutions? With Mathematica I've gotten the idea that the number of solutions is the product of the degrees $\deg (p) \deg (q)$, but I don't know in which direction I need to search to find this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a famous but non trivial result of Bézout known as Bézout's theorem. More exactly, the number of solutions in the projective plane counted with their multiplicity is $\deg(P)\deg(Q)$.